# Listview row leaves extra space between items

Tags: listview, react-native, jsx

I am trying to make a Listview on React-Native using dataobjects as the following:

```
const dataObjects = [
        {title: '1', description: 'First Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '2', description: 'Second Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '3', description: 'Third Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '4', description: 'Fourth Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '5', description: 'Fifth Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '6', description: 'Sixth Description', type: 'key'},
        {title: '7', description: 'Seventh Description', type: 'toogle'},   
        ... 
    ]
```

And my render method:

```
let remoteTemplate;
if (rowData.type == "key") {
    remoteTemplate = (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.key} onPress={() =>  alert("sd")}>
            <Text style={styles.basickey} >{rowData.title} - {rowData.description}</Text>                
        </TouchableOpacity>     
      ) 
    } else {
        remoteTemplate = (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.key2} onPress={() =>  alert("sd")}>
        <Text style={styles.toggle} >{rowData.title} - {rowData.description}</Text>              
        </TouchableOpacity>     
        )           
    }    
    return  (  
        remoteTemplate 
    )
```

And these are my styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
container: {  
},
swiper: {       
    paddingTop: Metrics.navBarHeight, 
},  
key: { 
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB',  
    width: (Metrics.screenWidth/4),  
    height: 60
},  
key2: { 
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB',  
    width: (Metrics.screenWidth/2), 
    height: 120
},  
basickey: {
    textAlign: 'center',
},
toggle: {
    textAlign: 'center', 
}, 
keysWrapper: { 
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row',   
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
},     
text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor:  '#9DD6EB', 
    color:  '#FFFFFF',      
}, 
});
```

[Snapshot of current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G929E.png)

As you may see, listview is rendered properly, however I want the row to use the white spaces left between listview rows. Please see the image. In this case, the 8.,11.,12. and 13.th items should shift to top.

Anybody have any idea how I can solve this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help you [Auto responsive grid layout library for ReactNative](https://github.com/xudafeng/autoresponsive_react_native_sample)